# How to prevent client side spoofing with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

After authenticating my user using Firebase, I have the user object (which has a Uid, which can be got using getUid. I also have his phone number.

But each time the app makes an http request to my site, how does my site know it is talking to my app, and not someone pretending to be my app ?

Does firebase have any feature where I can use some token or something when communicating with my app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use tokens:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

You get a token from firebase, and send it to your server. Your server checks with Google if the token is authentic.